# TP-LINK TL-WR840N Router hanging after firmware update

Tags: networking, router, firmware

After trying to install my router to the newest version so that the language can change from Chinese to English, it like crashed and the LAN cable lights are always on even when nothing is plugged in except the power cable. I have tried to reset it using the reset button by pressing for some seconds but nothing is happening.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you perform this update over wireless? It sounds like something happened in the transfer to corrupt the firmware image.

Answer (score 1):

You need to recover the router firmware.
(Always use a Ethernet cable when updating firmware)

These routers have tftp recovery for this situation.

1. Make sure you have downloaded the oldest available firmware, and make sure it's the right revision for the routers version number found on the underside sticker.
2. Download a tftp server program for the O.S you are using. Example, "pumpkin tftp" or "tftpd". Put your downloaded & extracted image in a folder of a known location like "c:\tftp" for Windows or in the home folder on Linux. Open the program, link the program to the chosen folder where the extracted image is. Make sure the tftp program is set to automatically allow download requests. You may need to make an exception for the tftp program in your firewall, or disable it while you do the firmware upgrade.
3. Set your PC to a static IP address of 192.168.0.66 with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0.
4. Make sure the tftp program is running, unplug the router for 15-30 seconds. Hold down the reset button while powering the router back up. (Holding for 3-8. Seconds on power up, the router will now try to reach out to 192.168.0.66 for the firmware image.)

Be patient, it can take up to ten minutes for the firmware to load properly on the router. (Now is a good time to grab a cup of coffee.)

That should be it, after you recover the firmware go ahead and redownload the latest image from tplink for this routers version number. You can upload it normally via the routers webgui.

Never upgrade over wireless, it's an easy way to make your router a paper weight.

A more detailed description of the recovery process can be found on the tp-link website, or in this video ~ https://youtu.be/0k1sxwX5pMk

Good luck!